# Read from every node in MongoDB MongoAtlas

Tags: mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I'm studying the theory based on NO-SQL Databases, trying to implements some examples in python.
Until now everything is clear, just because I've tried to do some simple queries on collections, following some simple tutorials.

Now my question regards **reading**. My understanding are that NO-SQL DBs such as MongoDB, perform bulk load, especially in the reading mode.

Now I have a collection which contains 60K of tweets and I'd like to read equally from every node.

**THIS IS HOW I'D LIKE TO READ**

- 20K tweets from the 1st node (Primary);
- 20K tweets  from the 2nd node (1st slave);
- 20K tweets  from the 3rd node (2nd slave);

Is it possible to do in **MongoDB Atlas**? If yes how can I achieve that? How can it be implemented in Python?

Sorry for the question but I'm kind of new in this topic

Answer (score 1):

Replica sets are used for redundancy, not for load balancing. When you read from secondaries you may receive stale data. Generally you would always read from primary if you want current data.

If you do not require current data, you can read from secondaries. One use case for this is performing analytics queries that are 1) expensive 2) generally still work OK on stale data. In this case you can indicate that a particular node is hidden from regular operations and is to be used specifically for analytics queries.

To distribute read load across multiple nodes, you would use a sharded cluster.

Comment: Ok, How can I implement read load across multiple node in MongoDB Atlas with a sharded cluster?

Comment: You need to select a shard key that distributes your data evenly across shards.

Comment: Is there a example where I can see how to do that? Sorry, I'm new in this topic, and don't know yet how to solve some kind of problems